# AWS Route 53: Changing automatically created NS records

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I created two public hosted zones in AWS Route 53 with the following records (I'm omitting SOA records):

```
Public Hosted Zone: domain.com
(auto-generated) NS domain.com: ns-xx1.awsdns-yy.net. ns-xx2.awsdns-yy.org. ns-xx3.awsdns-yy.co.uk. ns-xx4.awsdns-yy.com.
(manually added) NS sub.domain.com: ns-aa1.awsdns-yy.net. ns-aa2.awsdns-yy.org. ns-aa3.awsdns-yy.co.uk. ns-aa4.awsdns-yy.com.
```

and

```
Public Hosted Zone: sub.domain.com
(auto-generated) NS domain.com: ns-aa1.awsdns-yy.net. ns-aa2.awsdns-yy.org. ns-aa3.awsdns-yy.co.uk. ns-aa4.awsdns-yy.com.
```

Due to a mistake, my hosted zone `sub.domain.com` was deleted. I manually re-created `sub.domain.com`, however new NS and SOA records were auto-generated by Route 53.

In order to fix the subdomain delegation, I see two possibilities:

1. Change the NS records on my hosted zone `domain.com` to point to the new and auto-generated NS records of my `sub.domain.com` hosted zone.
2. Change the auto-generated NS records of `sub.domain.com` to match the NS records already configured on my hosted zone `domain.com`.

I tested both options and verified that only (1) works. On [AWS Route 53 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html), I found several entries advising users not to change auto-generated NS and SOA records of public hosted zones. Since the AWS UI and CLI allow modification of these entries, I believe there are use cases where changes to these records are allowed/necessary. I'm wondering what these use cases are.

Comment: It is is used (in step 6) when [Configuring White-Label Name Servers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html#white-label-name-servers-update-ns-soa-records)

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to change the NS records delegating the subdomain in the TLD to reflect the new auto generated sub domains NS servers.

This is because your sub domain zone is only hosted on the NS servers provided by AWS. So if you edit the auto generated sub domain SOA to point some where else you will just get null responses.

If you want to control your NS delegations a little more in the future you can generate a [reusable delegation set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/route-53-concepts.html#route-53-concepts-reusable-delegation-set) and use that next time you want to create a hosted zone.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I think that doesn't answer my questions regarding other use cases for having NS and SOA records editable in public hosted zones. Can you think of other use cases?

Comment: @Trein I can't think of any thing unless you were doing some weird stuff with DNS migrations. where you might move delegations around.  I mean technically you can do like redirects buy changing the SOA NS records to a new set of NS servers but I would suggest that's not best practice. you also risk having no more authoritative name servers in the setup.